# How is a pgf key defined?

Tags: pgfkeys

The following code illustrates that I don't understand one of the most basic things about `pgfkeys`. Namely, what it takes for a key to be defined. I've read through section 87.3 and following sections of the manual, but it still left me a bit fuzzy about when a key has been defined.

I originally thought that running a style with a list like `{assignlabel}` was sufficient to define the `assignlabel` key. It seems not. Is this because I have not assigned the `/assignlabel` key a value?

If I run the code below, I get

```
ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key
'/printdoctable/assignlabel/' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps
you misspelled it.
```

However, if I uncomment the `.estore` line, this error goes away. I don't understand why. That line just stores any assigned value to the macro, `\assignlabel`, right? I still have not assigned any value to the key, so why is it now defined? And it seems the `/.is choice` handler doesn't suffice to define it either. What does the `.estore` line do that is special here?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pgfkeys
{
  /printdoctable/.is family, /printdoctable,                                                                                                 
  default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel,
  },
  assignlabel/.is choice,
  % assignlabel/.estore in = \assignlabel,                                                                                                                                                                                     
  assignlabel/true/.estore in={\assignlabel},                                                                                 
  assignlabel/false/.estore in={\assignlabel},                                                                               
}  
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintDocTable}{O{}}
{
  \pgfkeys{/printdoctable, default, #1}%                                                                                                              
 %\assignlabel                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                  

\begin{document}
\PrintDocTable[assignlabel=false]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to highlight a few key features of [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102364/discussion-between-faheem-mitha-and-schrodingers-cat), which is too long to be fully reviewed here.

First and foremost, the question seems to be how one can define a pgf key. The short answer is that

```
 assignlabel/.is choice,
```

does that already,

```
 default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel,
  },
```

is not needed for that.

Then there is the question why your code does not work. This is because in your code `assignlabel` needs an argument. To make the error go away, it is sufficient to add a default to `assignlabel`, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pgfkeys
{
  /printdoctable/.is family, /printdoctable,                                                                                                 
  default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel,
  },
  assignlabel/.is choice,
  assignlabel/true/.estore in={\assignlabel},                                                                                 
  assignlabel/false/.estore in={\assignlabel},                                                                               
  assignlabel/.default=true,                                                                                                                                                                                     
}  
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintDocTable}{O{}}
{
  \pgfkeys{/printdoctable, default, #1}%                                                                                                              
 %\assignlabel                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                  

\begin{document}
\PrintDocTable[assignlabel=false]
\end{document}
```

does not cause an error (but is at this point also not too useful either).

Then it was mentioned in the chat that if you only want a Boolean, you may be better off with the `/.is if` key. This key is described in the pgfmanual v3.1.4 on p. 974

[image]

The code example here is very good in that it illustrates what the key does. [Paul's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521023/194703) adds another example.

Unfortunately, the v3.1.4 code example of `/.is choice` is IMHO less than optimal.

[image]

There are two issues:

1. First, as you pointed out in the [TeX chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52968687#52968687) and our chat, the roles of `butt cap` and `round cap` are swapped.
2. Moreover, the first three `/.style` keys should really be `/.code` keys.

This [issue has been reported](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/808) and will most likely be resolved in the next version of pgf.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. My ultimate goal is to define a boolean key, but let's set that aside for the moment. This question is simply to ask why the code stops complaining about `assignlabel` being undefined once the `assignlabel/.estore in = \assignlabel,`  has been added. The `.is choice` code isn't really relevant, and if it makes the question less confusing, I could delete it. I'm more interested in understanding what's going on here than achieving a specific goal. Unexpected results always particularly concern me, because that's a clear sign I don't understand something.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Your code also works if you remove `, default` from `\pgfkeys{/printdoctable, default, #1}% `, i.e. use `\pgfkeys{/printdoctable,  #1}%  ` instead. At the moment the way you use `default` does not make too much sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I'm unclear whether the code `default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel,
  }` actually serves any purpose if `assignlabel` isn't given a value. I earlier thought it initializes the key `assignlabel`, but apprently not.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `asssignlabel` gets "initialized" by `assignlabel/.is choice,`.

Comment: So, does `default/.style = { assignlabel, }` do anything at all?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It would do something if `assignlabel` was a style that can be called without argument, which in its current version it cannot (you could rectify this by defining an `assignlabel/.default`) and if the directories work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102364/discussion-between-faheem-mitha-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat In you last example code, you can use `assignlabel/true/.style={mylabel=true}` and `assignlabel/false/.style={mylabel=false}`.  And `mylabel/.store in=\assignlabel` is sufficient.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Well, I didn't update my answer since all these things were mentioned in the very extensive chat, the one you are saying, the `/.is if` and many many more.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution (if I understand your request) where I define a new if (`\ifprintdoctableassignlabel`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifprintdoctableassignlabel

\pgfkeys
{
  /printdoctable/.is family,
  /printdoctable,
  assignlabel/.is if=printdoctableassignlabel,
  default/.style={assignlabel=true},
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintDocTable}{O{}}
{
  \pgfkeys{/printdoctable,default,#1}%
  \ifprintdoctableassignlabel
  assignlabel is true
  \else
  assignlabel is false
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDocTable\par
\PrintDocTable[assignlabel=false]\par
\PrintDocTable[assignlabel=true]    
\end{document}
```

The result:

> assignlabel is true
>
> assignlabel is false
>
> assignlabel is true

Here is an example using an `.is choice` handler:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifprintdoctableassignlabel

\pgfkeys
{
  /printdoctable/.is family,
  /printdoctable,
  %
  assignlabel/.is if=printdoctableassignlabel,
  assignlabel/.default=true,
  %
  label/.is choice,
  label/a/.code={\def\printdoctablelabel{choice a}},
  label/b/.code={\def\printdoctablelabel{choice b}},
  label/c/.code={\def\printdoctablelabel{choice c}},
  %
  predefined values/.style={
    assignlabel=true,
    label=a,
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintDocTable}{O{}}
{%
  \pgfkeys{/printdoctable,predefined values,#1}%
  \ifprintdoctableassignlabel%
  assignlabel is true%
  \else%
  assignlabel is false%
  \fi%
  \space(label=\printdoctablelabel)%
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDocTable[label=b]

\PrintDocTable[assignlabel=false]

\PrintDocTable[assignlabel,label=c]

\end{document}
```

The result:

> assignlabel is true (label=choice b)
>
> assignlabel is false (label=choice a)
>
> assignlabel is true (label=choice c)

Comment: Hi @Paul. Thank you for the answer. You seem to have interpreted my question as "how do I implement a boolean using pgfkeys", when actually it was "why am I seeing this behavior?". But have an upvote anyway.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks. Just a remark about your question and other answers: the use of the `.estore in` handler is not relevant. Here, using the simpler `.store in` handler is enough and does not change all the explanations.

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes, I guess `estore` is not required. I've just got into the habit of using it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It is exactly as if you always use `\edef` instead of `\def`....

Comment: Are `.estore` and other e-things best avoided then?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Avoid them ? No. Just use them wisely: when the value to be stored must be expanded before.

Comment: So, generally speaking, `.store` etc. should be the default unless there is reason to expand the value before storage?

Comment: @FaheemMitha ...unless there is reason to _systematically_ expand the value before storage (to exceptionally expand the value, the caller of the key can use the `.expanded` handler).

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks very much to @Schrödinger's cat for very patiently answering my questions in chat, and for a helpful answer. I thought it would help if I could summarize the confusions that went into my question above. I think I understand things better now. While the PGF/TikZ manual is fine (and much better than most documentation out there, TeX-related or otherwise), there are a few things which could be emphasized.

Taking it from the top, for some reason, I seem to have thought that something like

```
default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel,
  },
```

actually initialized the key in question (in this case, `assignlabel`). As it turns out, this is horribly wrong. What the `.style` handler actually does is simply set up a sort of alias between the key `default` (inside the `printdoctable` namespace), and a list of key-value pairs. So if the `.style` handler is set on that key, then calling that calls that list of keys. But it doesn't actually define any of those keys. That's an important detail.

However, both the lines

```
assignlabel/.is choice,
```

and

```
assignlabel/.estore in = \assignlabel,
```

define a key. However, that is not enough, because the way I wrote it,`assignlabel` does not have a default value. So when I called

```
\pgfkeys{/printdoctable, default, #1}%
```

in my answer, the `default` part errored out, because it was effectively calling `assignlabel,`. Which doesn't have a default value at this point. And the key-value pairs that comprise the RHS of the `.style` expect a default if a value is not specified. Though I'm still not sure why the error message is:

```
I do not know the key '/printdoctable/assignlabel/'
```

instead of complaining that a value hasn't been assigned, which would certainly make for a better error message. But since Tex doesn't actually have variables or variable assignments, maybe it's a TeX artifact.

As @schrodinger's cat explained, one way around this is to assign `assignlabel` a default value with

```
assignlabel/.default=true,
```

An alternative is to write

```
default/.style =
  {
    assignlabel=false,
  },
```

which provides the required value to the key-value pair.

Comment: Looks good to me. +1 to you and Paul.